# UITableView can't smootly scrolling with IOS8 in iphone sdk?

Tags: uitableview, ios8, smooth-scrolling

I can use tableview to show multiple images in every row and which is scrollable. this time i am using cutomcell in tableview. So when Scrolling up and down is a bit sticky, it needs to flow without sticking or chopping. IOS7 has work perfectly but issue with IOS8, so anyone suggest me to do this Scrolling in better way.

My code is below for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
CellHomeFeedViewController *cell = (CellHomeFeedViewController*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[[CellHomeFeedViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:176.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.lblTime.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:71.0/255.0 green:72.0/255.0 blue:72.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.lblDetails.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:71.0/255.0 green:72.0/255.0 blue:72.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

        // Tap GestureRecognizer for User Image
        UITapGestureRecognizer *UserImg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UserNameORimageGesture:)];
        UserImg.delegate = self;
        UserImg.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        cell.imgUserPic.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.imgUserPic addGestureRecognizer:UserImg];

        // Tap GestureRecognizer for Name Label
        UITapGestureRecognizer *NameLabel = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UserNameORimageGesture:)];
        NameLabel.delegate = self;
        NameLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        cell.lblUsername.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.lblUsername addGestureRecognizer:NameLabel];

        // Tap GestureRecognizer for Time Label
        UITapGestureRecognizer *TimeLabel = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(UserNameORimageGesture:)];
        TimeLabel.delegate = self;
        TimeLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        cell.lblTime.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.lblTime addGestureRecognizer:TimeLabel];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *lbltotalCmt = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lbltotalCmtPress:)];
        lbltotalCmt.delegate = self;
        lbltotalCmt.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        cell.lblTotalComment.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.lblTotalComment addGestureRecognizer:lbltotalCmt];
        cell.lblTotalComment.tag=indexPath.row;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *lbltotalFav = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lbltotalFavPress:)];
        lbltotalFav.delegate = self;
        lbltotalFav.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        cell.lblTotalFavourite.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.lblTotalFavourite addGestureRecognizer:lbltotalFav];
        cell.lblTotalFavourite.tag=indexPath.row;

        cell.imgUserPic.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.lblUsername.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.lblTime.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.BtnCmnt.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.BtnGraph.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.BtnStar.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.btnMore.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.BtnFollow.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.BtnFollow addTarget:self action:@selector(btnFollowListPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.BtnCmnt addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnCmnt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.BtnGraph addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnGraph:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.BtnStar addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnStar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnMore addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    NSData *newdata = [[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"album_title"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *mystring=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (mystring.length > 200) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 200);
        mystring = [mystring substringWithRange:range];
    }

    if (mystring.length > 0) {
        cell.lblDetails.text = mystring;
    }
    cell.lblDetails.delegate = self;

    cell.lblTotalFavourite.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"favourite_count"]];
    cell.lblTotalComment.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comments_count"]];
    cell.lblTime.text = [[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"album_created"];
    cell.lblUsername.text = [[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user_name"];
    [cell.imgUserPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",mainImageURL,[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thum_image"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"400_loading_img.png"]];

    if ([[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"favourite_status"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [cell.BtnStar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_fvrte_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [cell.BtnStar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_fvrte_icon_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if ([[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"contact_allowed"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        if ([[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"is_following"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            cell.boolCheck = NO;
            cell.BtnFollow.hidden = YES;
            [cell.BtnFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            cell.boolCheck = YES;
            cell.BtnFollow.hidden = NO;
            [cell.BtnFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hp_add_frnd_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    } else {
        cell.boolCheck = NO;
        cell.BtnFollow.hidden = YES;
    }

    if ([[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"has_commented"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [cell.BtnCmnt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_comment_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [cell.BtnCmnt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_comment.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if ([[[arrAllPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"album_photo"] count]>0) {
        cell.boolPostType = YES;
        cell.tblSlider.hidden = NO;
        cell.tblSlider.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.tblSlider.delegate = self;
        cell.tblSlider.dataSource = self;
        [cell.tblSlider reloadData];
    } else {
        cell.boolPostType = NO;
        cell.tblSlider.hidden = YES;
    }

    return cell;
```

Below code of cutomcell:

```
> @implementation CellHomeFeedViewController @synthesize
> imgUserPic,tblSlider; @synthesize
> lblUsername,lblTime,lblDetails,lblTotalFavourite; @synthesize
> BtnCmnt,BtnGraph,BtnStar,btnMore,imgClock,ViewBottom,BtnFollow,btnReadMore;
> @synthesize lblTotalComment,boolCheck,boolPostType;
> 
> - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
>     self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
>     if (self)
>     {
>         appdelegate = (UBUBBLAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
>         
>         imgUserPic = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
>         [self.contentView addSubview:imgUserPic];
>         
>         lblUsername=[[UILabel alloc]init];
>         lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:176.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
>         lblUsername.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"calibri" size:14.0f];
>         [lblUsername setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
>         lblUsername.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
>         [self.contentView addSubview:lblUsername];
>         
>         lblTime=[[UILabel alloc]init];
>         [lblTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
>         lblTime.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"calibri" size:10.0f];
>         lblTime.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
>         [self.contentView addSubview:lblTime];
>         
>         appdelegate.lblLinkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:176.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
>         appdelegate.lblTxtColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
>         
>         lblDetails=[[KILabel alloc]init];
>         lblDetails.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"calibri" size:14.0f];
>         [lblDetails setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
>         lblDetails.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
>         lblDetails.numberOfLines = 50;
>         lblDetails.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
>         lblDetails.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
>         [self.contentView addSubview:lblDetails];
>         
>         tblSlider=[[UITableView alloc] init];
>         tblSlider.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
>         tblSlider.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
>         tblSlider.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
>         tblSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
>         [self.contentView addSubview:tblSlider];
>         
>         imgClock = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
>         imgClock.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_clock_icon.png"];
>         [self.contentView addSubview:imgClock];
>         
>         ViewBottom = [[UIView alloc] init];
>         ViewBottom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
>         [self.contentView addSubview:ViewBottom];
>         
>         btnMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         [btnMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_more_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:btnMore];
>         
>         BtnCmnt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         [BtnCmnt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_comment.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:BtnCmnt];
>         
>         BtnStar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         [BtnStar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_fvrte_icon_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:BtnStar];
>         
>         BtnFollow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         [BtnFollow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:BtnFollow];
>         
>         BtnGraph = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         [BtnGraph setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_status_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:BtnGraph];
>         
>         lblTotalComment=[[UILabel alloc]init];
>         lblTotalComment.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"calibri" size:12.0f];
>         [lblTotalComment setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
>         [lblTotalComment setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:lblTotalComment];
>         
>         lblTotalFavourite=[[UILabel alloc]init];
>         lblTotalFavourite.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"calibri" size:12.0f];
>         [lblTotalFavourite setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
>         [lblTotalFavourite setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
>         [ViewBottom addSubview:lblTotalFavourite];
>         
>     }
>     return self; }
> 
> -(void)layoutSubviews {
>     [super layoutSubviews];
>     
>     imgUserPic.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 36, 36);
>     imgClock.frame = CGRectMake(47, 27, 11, 12);
>     lblTime.frame = CGRectMake(61, 27, 260, 12);
>     
>     NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
>     paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
>     paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
>     
>     CGSize  labelSize;
>     
>     NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : self.lblUsername.font,
>                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
>     labelSize = [lblUsername.text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){250, 17000}
>                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading |
> NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
>                                            attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
>     [lblUsername setFrame:CGRectMake(47, 7, 250, 18)];
>     
>     CGFloat yOffset = 45.0;
>     NSDictionary * attributes1 = @{NSFontAttributeName : self.lblDetails.font,
>                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
>     labelSize = [lblDetails.text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){305, 17000}
>                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading |
> NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
>                                            attributes:attributes1 context:nil].size;
>     [lblDetails setFrame:CGRectMake(15, yOffset, 305, labelSize.height+30)];
>     
>     //btnReadMore.frame = CGRectMake(240, yOffset+labelSize.height-5, 80, 20);
>     
>     if (boolPostType) {
>         yOffset+=labelSize.height+20;
>         tblSlider.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset+10, 320, 182);
>         yOffset+=185;
>         BtnGraph.hidden = NO;
>         if (boolCheck) {
>             BtnCmnt.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 40, 40);
>             BtnGraph.frame = CGRectMake(75, 0, 50, 40);
>             BtnStar.frame = CGRectMake(141, 0, 40, 40);
>             lblTotalComment.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 40, 30);
>             lblTotalFavourite.frame = CGRectMake(174, 5, 40, 30);
>             btnMore.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 40);
>             BtnFollow.frame = CGRectMake(213, 0, 50, 40);
>         } else {
>             BtnCmnt.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 40, 40);
>             BtnGraph.frame = CGRectMake(95, 0, 50, 40);
>             BtnStar.frame = CGRectMake(186, 0, 40, 40);
>             lblTotalComment.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 40, 30);
>             lblTotalFavourite.frame = CGRectMake(219, 5, 40, 30);
>             btnMore.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 40);
>         }
>     } else {
>         yOffset+=labelSize.height+10;
>         BtnGraph.hidden = YES;
>         if (boolCheck) {
>             BtnCmnt.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 40, 40);
>             BtnStar.frame = CGRectMake(97, 0, 40, 40);
>             lblTotalComment.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 40, 30);
>             lblTotalFavourite.frame = CGRectMake(130, 5, 40, 30);
>             btnMore.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 40);
>             BtnFollow.frame = CGRectMake(195, 0, 50, 40);
>         } else {
>             BtnCmnt.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 40, 40);
>             BtnStar.frame = CGRectMake(136, 3, 30, 30);
>             lblTotalComment.frame = CGRectMake(35, 5, 40, 30);
>             lblTotalFavourite.frame = CGRectMake(165, 10, 35, 15);
>             btnMore.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 40);
>         }
>     }
> 
>     ViewBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset+15, 320, 40); }
> 
> -(CGFloat)requiredHieghtForCellInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
>     NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
>     paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
>     paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
>     
>     CGSize  labelSize;
>     
>     CGFloat yOffset = 45.0;
>     NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : self.lblDetails.font,
>                                   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName :paragraphStyle};
>     labelSize = [lblDetails.text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){305, 17000}
>                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading |
> NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
>                                            attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
>     
>     yOffset+=labelSize.height;
>     
>     if (boolPostType)
>         yOffset+=205;
>     else
>         yOffset+=10;
>     
>     yOffset+=60;
>     
>     return yOffset; }
> 
> @end
```

Comment: TL, didn't read (much). However, I see a `NSData` to `NSString` conversion in the cell. I don't know how **big** this data(string) really is, but it is surely going to affect performance. Maybe only part of your issue, but yet it will affect. Why not convert the `NSData` once, and store strings itself in your array?

Answer (score 1):

if (cell==nil

Remove this if  statement and proceed. That line causing problem

njoy coding